# The major mode name of emacs-lisp

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, major-mode, eval-after-load

I want to load emacs init files faster, so I use the 'eval-after-load.
For example, when I load clojure file, I just put

```
(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
    'do-something)
```

It works.
But when I try

```
(eval-after-load 'emacs-lisp-mode
    'do-something)
```

It doesn't work. I wonder to know the right major mode name of emacs-lisp.
Thanks.

Comment: When Emacs starts it automatically opens a *scratch* buffer which is in lisp-interaction-mode. This mode is defined in lisp-mode.el. Which means that lisp-mode is *always* loaded when you start emacs, so `do-something` will run whether or not you wrap it in `eval-after-load`.

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [documentation of `eval-after-load`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html#index-eval_002dafter_002dload-896):

> eval-after-load LIBRARY FORM
>
> This function arranges to evaluate form at the end of loading the file LIBRARY, each time LIBRARY is loaded. If LIBRARY is already loaded, it evaluates form right away. Don't forget to quote form!
>
> […] LIBRARY can also be a feature (i.e., a symbol), in which case form is evaluated at the end of any file where `(provide LIBRARY)` is called.

You have to pass the name of the file or library, which defines the major mode, as argument.

While some modes are defined in files of the same name (e.g. `clojure-mode` in `clojure-mode.el`), many files a different name, especially if the actually define multiple major modes.

`emacs-lisp-mode` is defined in `lisp-mode.el`, along with some other modes for Emacs Lisp editing (e.g. `lisp-mode` as a generic Lisp language mode, or `lisp-interaction-mode` for `*scratch*` buffers).

Hence, use `(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode …`)

Also, you have to give a single sexp as second argument, so you'll likely want to use  `(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode '(do-something))`, to call the function `do-something`.

If you are using a snapshot build of Emacs, use `with-eval-after-load`, i.e. `(with-eval-after-load 'lisp-mode (do-something))`.  It allows for more than a single form, and doesn't require quoting.

Answer (score 2):

Just eval with `M-:` the variable `major-mode`. It actually is `emacs-lisp-mode`.
Note that `*scratch*` is actually in `lisp-interaction-mode`.

As to what you're trying to do, use `(eval-after-load "lisp-mode")`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @lunaryom, the arg passed to `eval-after-load` is not a function name but a feature name, which is basically a file name.  So you need to find the name of the file from which the function is loaded.
We could provide a feature like `eval-after-defun`, and indeed it might be a good idea to do so.  If you'd like such a thing, ask for it via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.